Github run job on pull request merge or closed from base main branch problems
Hey guys I have a bicep workflow, I am trying to run bicep-plan on pull request creation which I have done.
then I have bicep deploy and I want it to run on pull request base main branch only and only run when the pull request is closed or merged but when I run my code it just  skips the job
on:
  pull_request:
     types: [opened, closed]
     branches:
     - main
  workflow_dispatch: 


   

bicep-deploy:
name: 'Bicep Deploy'
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
if: github.base_ref == 'main' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true


it should be ok, can you share your full workflows and logs from the merged run?

@ShaykiAbramczyk I got it to work but instead of it using the same workflow run after merging it will run a new one is there a way to get it to run one workflow and just queue the bicep deploy job till the merge is done so its all on one workflow?
